# как сделать непрерывную бегущую строку из изображений чтобы она не обрывалась? без тега <marquee>

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, scss

я у меня получилось вот это но оно обрывается, я использую препроцессор scss

```
    &__box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    animation: main__box 10s linear infinite;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    max-width: 100%;
   }
@keyframes main__box {
0%{
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
100%{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если требуется "двигать" `background`, то используем `background-position` и при анимации двигаем его.

```css
.running-bg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('//i.imgur.com/cYyUPBA.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  
  animation: running-bg 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes running-bg {
  to {
    background-position-x: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="running-bg"></div>
```

---

Если требуется двигать блок какой-либо, то при помощи `transform`, но для красоты потребуется "репитить" блок, и желательно, чтобы он занимал 100% влока родителя.

```css
.running-bg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.running-bg img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: running-bg 10s linear infinite;
}

.running-bg img:nth-child(2) {
  left: 100%;
}

@keyframes running-bg {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="running-bg">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/cYyUPBA.png">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/cYyUPBA.png">
</div>
```